# How to rename file forth and back in java

Tags: java, file, zip, rename, document

I want to rename a file name xxx.docx to xxx.docx.zip then rename it back to xxx.docx in Java.

Here is my code.

```
File file = new File(path);
File file2 = new File(path+".zip");
file.renameTo(file2);
File file3 = new File(file.getPath());
file2.renameTo(file3);
```

It won't work. Thank you.

Edit : The problem is I forgot to close the doc before renaming it.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? What possible purpose does it serve?

Comment: `File.renameTo()` returns a boolean, and you don't check for the results. Use java.nio.files instead (`Files.move()`)

Comment: You are probably not doing exactly this; you are most likely doing other things with the file in between. Explain in more detail what your code is doing exactly. Note that renaming might not work if some process has the file open.

Comment: I want to change file type .docx to .zip to extract it  and get the xml files inside. Now I found the problem thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code like that works. Most probably some other process has locked the file and made it read only. You have either opened it in word (since it is docx file) or something like that. Maybe it is in a readonly location.

The code is working though. Try with different file and you will see it is fine (I tried it).